# decide page based on number of parameters - htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am writing RewriteRule(s) on htaccess which decides which page it redirect to based on the number of parameters.

for example, "http://mysite.com/tommy"
this will redirect to "mysite.com/user.php?user=tommy"

whereas, "http://mysite.com/tommy/pets"
will redirect to "mysite.com/show.php?user=tommy&category=pets"

note, the first URL has only one parameters and it redirects to user.php and second URL has two parameters and it redirects to show.php instead.

please help, and thanks in advance!

Currently...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ category.php?userId=$1&category=$2 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?userId=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. "I am writing..." you said. If you already wrote it, what's the problem then? If you haven't made it work as you want, show what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, for anyone else who need this too...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?userId=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?userId=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?userId=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ category.php?userId=$1&category=$2 [L]
```